# String function similar to STUFF in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

How can we implement SQL Function STUFF in Hive?

Example:

```
SELECT STUFF('abcdef', 2, 3, 'ijklmn');  

Result is:
---------   
aijklmnef   

(1 row(s) affected)
```

One logic which can be used is using sub string and concat:

```
 SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTR('abcdef',0,1),'ijklmn',SUBSTR('abcdef',5,LENGTH('abcdef')));
 ----------

 +------------+--+
 | aijklmnef  |
 +------------+--+
 1 row selected (0.322 seconds)
```

Is there any other simple logic to implement STUFF in hive?

Comment: you can write your own UDF for this, to know how to write UDF refer this link  - http://blog.matthewrathbone.com/2013/08/10/guide-to-writing-hive-udfs.html

Answer (score 1):

From your question, I understood you are expecting similar functionality of STUFF in SQL server.

> The T-SQL STUFF command is used to concatenate the results together.

If you have input of following type:

**INPUT:**

[image]

Then STUFF will give you an output after Concatenation:

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Similar Query like Stuff in HIVE is below,

```
select id
    ,name
    ,dob
    ,concat_ws(',',collect_list(location)) as location
from test_analysis
group by id
    ,name
    ,dob
```