# HQL - Concatenate Column Values from Multiple Rows into a Single Column having duplicate id

Tags: hibernate, hql

I want to concatenate the duplicate id to single row.

```
 user.id | group.name        
    1    |     a
    1    |     b
    1    |     c
```

I want it like :-

```
user.id | group.name        
   1    |   a,b,c
```

All I want it in hql. How do I write in hql query where User left join Group. Need Help!!!

Comment: Concatenation is not the database job. It's the presentation layer job.

Comment: Like array_to_string( array_agg (group.name),' , ') in SQL, I want it in HQL.

Comment: There is no such thing is HQL. But again, this is a bad idea. Leave the presentation-related code in the presentation layer. Not in the database layer.

Comment: Ok Thanks. But I want to omit multiple rows with same id. Can  u suggest how is it possible in hql with select??

Comment: You don't want to omit them. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to concatenate their name.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40623523/string-function-similar-to-stuff-in-hive